# Is it possible to manipulate an apk file to create a fake update for an android app?

Tags: security

I am downloading updates for my android apps through a 3rd party android market and not the google play, because Google bans some apps in my area.

I wonder if this 3rd party market can create fake updates for the existing apps in my phone and inject their malicious code into that app and send them through their market to my android phone as a new update and then after i updated my app they can run their own code inside the manipulated app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android operating system checks that any app updates are signed with the same key as the original app. If the third party market signs the app for you, then they could create fake updates. If the app delivered is signed with your developer key then the market cannot provide updates as they would need access to your developer key.

Having said this, if the app market uninstalled then re-installed the app (rather than just updating it) then they could effectively change keys, but the uninstall would also remove other things (like local file system data, user preferences, etc).